# Java sockets application with two listeners hanging

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm running a client and server on my local machine and trying to send text messages between the two. Both sides are able to read and write. I'm using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` because I need to serialize objects. [Github repo](https://github.com/zinyosrim/client-server-object-streams.git)

My issue is when I try to send messages from both sides, they don't get through to the other side and the listeners hang.

`Host.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Host {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private int portNumber = Settings.PORT;

    public Host() {
        acceptConnection();
        CommandListener commandListener = new CommandListener(in);
    }

    private void acceptConnection() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getIn() {
        return in;
    }
}
```

`Client.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    private int portNumber = Settings.PORT;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Client(String ip) {
        connectToHost(ip);
        CommandListener commandListener = new CommandListener(in);
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    private void connectToHost(String ip) {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(ip, portNumber);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + ip);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + ip);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `CommandListener.java` class is a thread which is started independently by both the client and the server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class CommandListener implements Runnable{
    private ObjectInputStream in;

    public CommandListener(ObjectInputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        String inboundCmd;
        try {
            System.out.println("listener running, waiting for inbound command");
            inboundCmd = (String) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("listener read inbound command" + inboundCmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Both hang after printing out `listener running, waiting for inbound command`. 
Here's how I start the client and the server:

`RunHost.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class RunHost {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Host host = new Host();
        ObjectOutputStream out = host.getOut();
        out.writeObject("host sending");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

`RunClient.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class RunClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Client client = new Client("localhost");
        ObjectOutputStream out = client.getOut();
        out.writeObject("client sending");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**The reason why it seems like both the host and the client are "hanging" is simply because nobody managed to write anything before listening to the other party.**

You should be running `RunHost.java` before `RunClient.java`. Starting from there, you can trace the program:

1. Construct a new Host (i.e. `RunHost.java` is ran)
2. Blocks and wait for a client socket to connect
3. Construct a new Client (i.e. `RunClient.java` is ran)
4. Both `ServerSocket`'s and `ClientSocket`'s input and output streams are initialised
5. Both `ServerSocket` and `ClientSocket` start constructing `CommandListener`
6. Both `ServerSocket` and `ClientSocket` start listening for an input

See the problem yet? The main issue is because you call the method `run()` within the `CommandListener` constructor, so both Server and Client side start to block on listening without anyone having sent anything.

A quick fix would be to take out the `run()` call from the `CommandListener` constructor function, and then call it separately when you are ready for it.

For example:

Change the constructor in `CommandListener.java` to:

```
public CommandListener(ObjectInputStream in) {
    this.in = in;
}
```

Add a way to get the `CommandListener` for the client in `Client.java` (note that this means you should store the `CommandListener` by doing `cl = new CommandListener(in);` in the `Client` constructor):

```
public CommandListener getCL() {
    return cl;
}
```

Change `RunClient.java` to something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Client client = new Client("localhost");
    ObjectOutputStream out = client.getOut();
    out.writeObject("client sending");
    out.flush();
    CommandListener cl = client.getCL();
    cl.run();
}
```

And lastly, call `CommandListener`'s `run()` method in `Host`'s constructor:

```
public Host() {
    acceptConnection();
    CommandListener commandListener = new CommandListener(in);
    commandListener.run();
}
```

And it should work as per expected.

But to be honest, given the mess that `CommandListener` is causing, you may want to reconsider having that class in the first place. I mean, over here it doesn't seem to be necessary, so...

P/S Feel free to let me know if anything is unclear/ it still does not work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I applied your recommendations, but I'm still having the same issue. I didn't understand what you meant with having that class in the first place?

Comment: Here's the full code:
`Host.java`: https://pastebin.com/hyT8HWTf
`Client.java`: https://pastebin.com/0mPu7H0w
`ComamndListener.java`: https://pastebin.com/a3nGarXk
`RunClient.java`: https://pastebin.com/b6Ly75xR
`RunHost.java`: https://pastebin.com/8rLLBFRS (was unchanged)

Just run `RunHost.java` before `RunClient.java`

Comment: Also, I was just saying that since `CommandListener` is not really doing much (at this point in time), you may want to remove it completely :P

Comment: it worked. the commands were exchanged. But, I wasn't able to exchange more than one string. I discovered that I had two issues with my code: 1. I didn't have a while loop which was listening continiously. 2. The listener wasn't running in a thread. Will post the updated code tomorrow. Anyway, thanks for your support.